# Define language when using facebook graph-api receiving feeds

Tags: php, facebook, graph

I'm using Facebook's PHP-lib to reading a user-feed through the api call.
Therefore I created a dummy-application to use app-id and app-key to authenticate.

I'm receiving the feed data but the default status messages generated by Facebook (e.g. 'User has changed his profile photo.') are in english.

Is there a way to set the language of these messages?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

See the section titled “Specifying Locale” here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/:

> *“If your app needs the ability to retrieve localized content in the language of a particular locale, add the `locale` parameter.”*

Comment: I have swum for 4 oceans for looking for another answers but the best answer is beside my home. !!! Thank you very much. I have been looking for this. By the way, I solution what I found is `$country = $response->getGraphObject()->getField('location')->getField('location')->getField('country');`